# Difficulty plotting categorial numeric values on x-axis of plot.line() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, plot

I would like to create a line plot using data where the x-value will either be 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0 (categorical).

However, when I run the following code, it prints the x-axis as a range of values (0.5-3.5) rather than just the values whereas I only want to see 3 values (1.0, 2.0 and 3.0) on the x-axis:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
fig.tight_layout(pad=3.2)
 
newdata = newdf.groupby('smoking-number').mean().reset_index()
sem = newdf.groupby('smoking-number').sem().reset_index()
newdata.plot.line(x='smoking-number',y='distance', yerr= sem, ax=axes[0],legend=False)
newdata.plot.line(x='smoking-number',y='duration', yerr= sem, ax=axes[1],legend=False)
upperbounddistance = max(newdata[['distance']].values)+max(sem[['distance']].values)
lowerbounddistance = min(newdata[['distance']].values)-min(sem[['distance']].values)
upperboundduration = max(newdata[['duration']].values)+max(sem[['duration']].values)
lowerboundduration = min(newdata[['duration']].values)-min(sem[['duration']].values)
axes[0].set_ylim(lowerbounddistance,upperbounddistance)
axes[0].set_xlim(0.5,3.5)
axes[1].set_ylim(lowerboundduration,upperboundduration)
axes[1].set_xlim(0.5,3.5)
axes[0].set_ylabel("Wayfinding distance")
axes[0].set_xlabel("Smoking frequency")
axes[1].set_ylabel("Wayfinding duration")
axes[1].set_xlabel("Smoking frequency")
```

[image]

I would be so grateful if anybody could give me a helping hand!

```
distance
10  48.146090
13  98.877301
17  66.670310
19  95.764316
21  78.737108
22  48.404197
25  63.910073
27  40.862231
28  50.223985
30  38.724922

duration
10  40.976006
13  90.093298
17  88.349603
19  82.737323
21  72.579054
22  40.059987
25  57.629693
27  38.419589
28  40.834470
30  34.813547

smoking-number
10  1.0
13  1.0
17  1.0
19  1.0
21  1.0
22  1.0
25  3.0
27  1.0
28  1.0
30  1.0
```

Comment: Have you tried ```axes.set_xticks([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])```?

Comment: Thank you so much!! Might you know why the values on the Y-axis on the top graph are not at the bottom and the top of the axis (like on the bottom graph), and if so, how can I change this? :)